# Angular 2/4: How to call Web Apis via Http Post with parameters?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie with regards to Angular. I've looked at several places and most of the examples are extremely complicated. Is there something simple which I can start from? Something that calls a web api which accepts 2 parameter and returns an object

```
[HttpPost("GetHomePageData")]
        public HomePageData GetHomePageData(int P1, int P2)
        {
            //
        }

public class HomePageData
    {
        public int AddressCount { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: "I've looked at several places and most of the examples are extremely complicated" If it's complicated for you, try looking at something more basic first. Trying to run before you can walk will always be complicated.

Comment: Seriously no examples mate

Comment: There are a lot of examples. Can you provide a few links that you found but were not useful to you?

Comment: for example https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example... this does not show how to pass the 2 int parameters which I have as an example

Comment: You do not seem to understand how web works in general. You call an API endpoint by using HTTP. Read up an intro on that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Angular's official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) you can see examples like this:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out! Actually chrome helped me!